# "Time Limit Exceeded" for a Haskell solution to Knapsack

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

This is a very standard [Knapsack](https://open.kattis.com/problems/knapsack) problem from Kattis. Below is a straightforward dynamic programming solution in Haskell:

```haskell
{-# Language OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Arrow ((>>>))
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Data.Array
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C

main = C.interact solve

solve = C.words >>> fmap readInt >>> divideInput
        >>> fmap (solveCase >>> toBS)
        >>> C.unlines
  where readInt = C.readInt >>> fromJust >>> fst

divideInput :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
divideInput [] = []
divideInput (c:n:ls) = (c : n : this) : divideInput that
  where (this, that) = splitAt (2*n) ls

solveCase :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
solveCase (c:n:os) = [[length is], is]
  where is = recover (n, c) []

        recover (i, j) rs | table ! (i, j) == 0 = rs
                          | table ! (i, j) == table ! (i-1, j) =
                            recover (i-1, j) rs
                          | table ! (i, j) == vi + (table ! (i-1, j-wi)) =
                            recover (i-1, j-wi) ((i-1):rs)
          where (vi, wi) = objs ! i

        objs :: Array Int (Int, Int)
        objs = listArray (1, n) $ pairs os
        pairs [] = []
        pairs (v:w:os) = (v,w) : pairs os

        -- table[i][j] is the max value that can be achieved with
        -- objects [1..i] where the total weight of selected
        -- objects is <= j.
        table :: Array (Int, Int) Int
        table = array bnds [(ij, fill ij) | ij <- range bnds]
          where 
            bnds = ((0,0), (n,c))
            fill (i, w) | i == 0 || w == 0 = 0
                        | w < wi = vx
                        | otherwise = max vx (vy+vi)
              where vx = table ! (i-1, w)
                    vy = table ! (i-1, w - wi)
                    (vi, wi) = objs ! i

toBS :: [[Int]] -> C.ByteString
toBS [[n], is] = C.intercalate "\n"
                 [C.pack (show n), C.intercalate " " $ C.pack . show <$> is]
```

However, the code gives TLE once submitted to Kattis, which seems surprising given its *O(Cn)* complexity (picking from *n* objects with maximum capacity *C*). Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

I have already tried using mutable Arrays in ST monad. But mutable Arrays doesn't help here, which is not surprising because the DP arrays never need to be updated.

Profiled it on C=2000, n=2000, with values and weights uniform randomly picked between 1 and 20000. It took ~1.16 seconds. Full profile attached below:

```
     523,035,224 bytes allocated in the heap
     598,289,064 bytes copied during GC
     144,045,528 bytes maximum residency (4 sample(s))
         662,056 bytes maximum slop
             254 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       464 colls,     0 par    0.374s   0.394s     0.0008s    0.0196s
  Gen  1         4 colls,     0 par    0.141s   0.202s     0.0505s    0.1067s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.004s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.651s  (  0.664s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.515s  (  0.596s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  Total   time    1.166s  (  1.265s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.0%  (0.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    804,028,826 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  55.8% of total user, 52.5% of total elapsed
```

Comment: I tried one 2000x2000 instance and the program took about 1.5 seconds on my machine. 
 It isn't clear what the time limit means. Is it for a single test case or for all 30? If the latter, then it's a tad slow. Have you tried profiling?

Comment: Is it possible that the use of plain lists may be inefficient?

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m., according to Kattis judging rules (https://open.kattis.com/help/judgements), the time limit is per file. Though, for this particular problem, each input file can contain up to 30 large testcases with (2000, 2000). 

Profile info now appended to my original question.

Comment: Memory consumption looks a bit excessive. Perhaps a mutable array of unboxed Ints can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just managed to get an accepted variant using IOUArray and IOArray.  Also need to tweak the code to reduce the use of Lists as much as possible. Accepted with 1.61 seconds.

I tried STUArray/STArray early on and thought they would offer the same performance as IOUArray/IOArray. However, it turns out that even if STUArray/STArray based solution used less memory and time than functional Arrays, it still failed the last test file for TLE.

I saw the fastest accepted Haskell solution used only 0.38 second. I am curious what they did to make it that fast. My accepted code is attached below along with some profile info. Any ideas to further improve its performance are welcome.

```
{-# Language OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Arrow ((>>>))
import Control.Monad
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Data.Array.IO
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C
  
main = do
  inStr <- C.getContents
  solveCases $ (C.words >>> fmap readInt) inStr
  where readInt = C.readInt >>> fromJust >>> fst

solveCases :: [Int] -> IO ()
solveCases [] = return ()
solveCases (c:n:os) = do
  objs <- newArray (1, n) (0,0)
  os' <- fillObj objs n os
  table <- buildTable objs
  indices <- recover table objs n c []
  putStrLn $ show $ length indices
  putStrLn $ intercalate " " $ show <$> indices
  solveCases os'
  where 
    recover :: IOUArray (Int, Int) Int ->
               IOArray Int (Int, Int) ->
               Int -> Int -> [Int] -> IO [Int]
    recover table objs i j rs = do
      v <- readArray table (i, j)
      if (v == 0)
        then return rs
        else do
        v' <- readArray table (i-1, j)
        if (v == v')
          then recover table objs (i-1) j rs
          else do
          (_, wi) <- readArray objs i
          recover table objs (i-1) (j-wi) ((i-1):rs)
          
    fillObj :: IOArray Int (Int, Int) -> Int -> [Int] -> IO [Int]
    fillObj objs n vws = go 1 vws
      where go :: Int -> [Int] -> IO [Int]
            go i (v:w:vws) | i == n = writeArray objs i (v, w) >> return vws
                           | otherwise = do
                               writeArray objs i (v, w)
                               go (i+1) vws

    bnds = ((0,0), (n,c))

    -- table[i][j] is the max value that can be achieved with
    -- objects [0..i] such that the max selected weight is <= j.
    buildTable :: IOArray Int (Int, Int) -> IO (IOUArray (Int, Int) Int)
    buildTable objs = do
      table <- newArray bnds 0
      forM_ (range bnds) $ \(i, w) -> do
        when (i > 0 && w > 0) $ do
          (vi, wi) <- readArray objs i
          vx <- readArray table (i-1, w)
          if (w < wi)
            then do
            writeArray table (i, w) vx
            else do
            vy <- readArray table (i-1, w-wi)
            writeArray table (i, w) $ max vx (vy+vi)
      return table
```

```
      33,901,296 bytes allocated in the heap
         183,504 bytes copied during GC
          53,320 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
          36,792 bytes maximum slop
              33 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         2 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0002s
  Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.003s     0.0025s    0.0025s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.004s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.040s  (  0.048s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.003s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.006s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.040s  (  0.061s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.0%  (0.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    847,130,013 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  98.9% of total user, 79.3% of total elapsed
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show the final code.

Comment: okay, attached.